# Asp.net MVC validation . Validation seems to work but the values dont

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that allows an email list to be entered. I setup validation attribute which works fine but when validation fails the data gets messed up

```
 [HttpPost]
 
        public ActionResult Edit(ReportSubscription reportSubscription)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var rs = reportSubscription;
                _subscriptionsRepo.SaveSubscriptionChanges(rs.SubscriptionID.ToString(), rs.EmailTo, rs.Subject);

                return RedirectToAction("Subscription");

            }

            else {
               
                return View("EditSub");
            }
```

this is a partial of what I have in the view

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div style="width:500px;padding-left:0px">
                <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EmailTo, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "6", cols = "200" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailTo)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I submit an invalid I get the error message but the email is duplicated and labels on the screen are blank

Comment: You must add your model as parameter in the return in the else.
something like `return View(reportSubscription);`

Comment: I tried that but then it says the route doesn't exist. I have to use the EditSub

Comment: can you add your `HttpGet` function to your question?

Answer (score -1):

So it turned out to be a naming issue. I did get it working but have decided ASP.net is garbage and converted to a good framework.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).